# Save website into cache and load it in offline mode (Android)

Tags: java, android, caching

I tried to find an answer on my question, but I didn't find any result in the already opened questions.
I want to load a website in my Android app when I'm online and save it's data to cache.
When the user doesn't have Internet connection, it should be loaded from the cache.
The permissions in my app are:
        android.permission.INTERNET
        android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
        android.permisson.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
The code of the Activity

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize( 5 * 1024 * 1024 ); // 5MB
    webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess( true );
    webview.getSettings().setAppCachePath( "/KP");
    webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );

    try{
    if(isNetworkAvailable())
    {
        webview.clearCache(true);
        webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    }
    else{
        webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ONLY);
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        dlgAlert.setMessage("");
        dlgAlert.setTitle("Error");
        dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
        dlgAlert.create().show();
    }

    String url="https://google.com";
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webview.loadUrl(url);   
 }
```

This doesn't work and I can't find any more information about how to make it save cache and load it in offline mode.

Comment: What does not work exactly?

Comment: Exactly the page is not loading from the cache. The cache is not creating.

Comment: Don't reverse things and just start at the beginnening. So you say that at load the webpage is not placed in the cache. Are you sure? Do you know the path to the cache? Did you have a look if it contained files? That it contained the page?. A second remark is: even if it would be in cache why do you think it would be loaded from cache instead of url if no internet available? Please show the docu.